# Why is multiselect not updating?

Tags: bootstrap-4, multi-select, bootstrap-5, bsmultiselect

I am using bsMultislect with bootstrap 5. I have all the required dependant scripts, however, the multiselect element is only updated if the page is reloaded. When an option in another select (classNames) is selected, this should trigger an update in the multiselect. The script only works after a page reload and not with the change in the classNames select. I am aware there could be compatibility issues with bootstrap 5, however, the problem occurs in bootstrap 4 as well.

```
  <script>

$('#classNames').change(function(){ 
        var param = $('#classNames').val();
        localStorage.setItem('classParam',$('#classNames').val());
        
        
        var settingStd = {
    "async": false, 
    "url": '<?php echo site_url()."xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.php"; ?>',
    "method": "GET",
     "dataType":"Json",
    "data": { classes : param}
}

$.ajax(settingStd).done(function (restd) {
     
     $("#studentList").find("option").remove();
        var option1 = document.createElement('option');
        option1.setAttribute('value', 'All Students');
            option1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('All Students'));
            var option=null;
            for(var i =0; i<restd.length; i++){ 
                //console.log(restd[i].fName);
            option = document.createElement('option');
            option.setAttribute('value', restd[i].fName+" "+restd[i].lName);
            option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(restd[i].fName+" "+restd[i].lName));
                //console.log(option);
               $('#studentList').append(option);
            }
     $("#studentList").bsMultiselect();
});</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should push changes in data to the visual component (there are no auto monitoring). We call it reactiveness, but of course it is not obvious that options element list is only data for BsMultiSelect.

So call `UpdateData` of `BsMusltiSelect` if there were many changes and you want to refresh whole control, or particular option updates:

```
  var index =15;
          bsMultiSelect.updateOptionSelected(index);
          bsMultiSelect.updateOptionDisabled(index);
          bsMultiSelect.updateOptionHidden(index);
```

if 15 `option` was changed

There are also `pushers` for particalar option insert and remove.

"View page source" of this snippet can show how API works: https://dashboardcode.github.io/BsMultiSelect/snippetJs.html